# Return confusing boolean statement - refactoring

Tags: java, refactoring

I wrote a method:

```
private boolean checkIfCanBeSent(Product product, Type type, TypeToSend typeToSend) {
    boolean isDisabled = isStatusDisabled(product, type);
    boolean isManual = isManual(typeToSend);

    return !(isDisabled && !isManual);
}
```

it works properly, however during peer review got comment that this return statement is confusing. How to improve it and make it more readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three suggestions.

- Apply De Morgan's law to give an equivalent statement.
- It's easier to understand "enabled" than "not disabled".
- Don't give a variable the same name as a method.

So

```
boolean isEnabled = ! isStatusDisabled(product, type);
boolean isManualType = isManual(typeToSend);

return isEnabled || isManualType;
```

Comment: I would add that it may be easier to read without variables: just inline them directly into the return statement. The variable names add nothing over and above the names of the methods used to evaluate them.